# Не получается распарсить ответ от mysql. object(mysqli_result) и передать в массив php 7

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, php7

С толкнулся с непониманием того как распарсить ответ при отправке запроса к бд mysql. Базу подключил, запрос отправляю получаю это:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(1) }
```

В базе простая заполненная таблица стран из двух столбцов: `ID` 'name1':
в 3 строки: Россия, Польша, США

Вот код:

```js
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("83.120.144.358", "admin", "testa1", "admin_test);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM countries", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

var_dump($result);
```

Как мне эти названия стран вывести в нормальный массив используя конечно php 7? Помогите пожалуйста новичку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* проверка соединения */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Соединение не удалось: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* удаление выборки */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* закрытие соединения */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: ваш код выдает это `3 (???) 2 (??????) 1 (??????)` что это?

Comment: это не мой код, я дал ссылку на документацию по mysqli_fetch_assoc - код оттуда, у тебя отсутствует эта функция, она и преобразует объект в ассоциативный (на него ссылку дал) или нумерованный массив (нумерованный массив это mysqli_fetch_row  http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

вот этого куска кода у тебя нет:

     /* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

Comment: Ну понятно, он работает кстати, до меня дошло что скорее всего у меня кодировка походу слетела и поэтому 3 (???) 2 (??????) 1 (??????)

Comment: кодировка это ерунда, лучше изучи pdo подключение к бд, иначе в команду какую прийдёшь и там переучиваться заставят всё равно

Answer (score 1):

> Базу подключил

Это заблуждение. К базе подключаются совсем не так.
К сожалению, примеры для mysqli в мануале ужасающие. [Код для соединения с mysdli надо брать здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)

> Как мне эти названия стран вывести в нормальный массив

Для этого есть функция mysqli_fetch_all(). Соответственно, правильный код будет таким

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, $charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
$massiv = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM countries")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!! Единственное не понятно в этой строчке с методом `mysqli_set_charset` откуда переменная `$charset` ?